# Set chromedriver timeout in Appium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium, python-appium

I am using Appium python-client to test My Hybrid Android app. I was wondering if there is a place to add a timeout setting to chromedriver when find a WebElement? 
Because when the element to find does not exists, the appium stucks until the proxy timeout.

Here is my python unittest code:

```py
def test_reco(self):
  self.driver.switch_to_context('WEBVIEW_****')
  self.driver.implicity_wait(1000)
  reco = self.find_element_by_class_name('common_rec_title')
  self.assertIsNotNone(reco)
```

Appium stuck log is as follows:

[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /wd/hub/session/976526de-ede7-43bd-818edf329022/element/0.6988143097281722-71/element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/wd/hub/session/d425efe1180faa9977a1e1bedd7d7506/element/0.6988143097281722-71/element] with body: {"using": "class name", "value":"common_rec_title", "id":"0.6988143097281722-71"}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android version 6.0 or above version, You don't need to switch to WebView manually, appium takes care of it.

However, you need to update Android System WebView or Chrome browser from PlayStore.

Hope this helps.